# using useFormik in a conditional

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a react variable I have created using `const [mode, setMode] = useState(false)`, and I have a useFormik instance `const formik=useFormik(initialValues, schema, onSubmit)`.

Whenever the mode changes to `true`, I have to update the form. But, the problem is I can't use `useFormik` inside a conditional(my IDE gives an error), neither can I use useFormik in something like `useEffect`(IDE says can't use hook inside a callback which ain't a  react component).

How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: Explain better what is `update the form`

Comment: @ViniciusKatata , by `update the form` I mean, I have to reflect the changes in the initialValues in the form fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write conditional `useXXX`, but that doesn't mean you can't leave them there.

```
  const [mode, setMode] = useState(false)
  const flag = true
  const formik = useFormik(initialValues, schema, flag ? onSubmit : '')

  if (!flag) return null
  return flag ? formik.values : ''
```

I use couple of example to show how to do conditional code without breaking `useXXX`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer, what you need is a way to change the values based not only in the inputs that the user could input data.

There is an option to do that using `formik.setFieldValue`, you could use it in a `useEffect` that is triggered when your mode changes. Like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (mode) {
    formik.setFieldValue('email', 'foo@bar.com');
  }
}, [mode]);
```